# Bizrate Pop up onsite merchant code disables Magento pages

Tags: javascript, magento

We implemented the BizRate merchant rating code on our Magento site, and unfortunately, it makes the rest of the page's functionality die (zoom images won't load and the all-important "Add to Cart" button doesn't work.

Here's the code I'm loading via Aheadworks Z Blocks (along with our BBB Rating)

```
<table style="width: 312px; background-color: #ffffff; height: 60px; border: 0px solid #949494;" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="2"><br /> <!-- BEGIN: Bizrate Medal (112x37 pixels) -->
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var bizrate={small:"true"};
<script src="//medals.bizrate.com/medals/js/16820_medal.js" type="text/javascript">
// ]]></script>
<p><a class="br-button"> <img usemap="#16820_medal" src="//medals.bizrate.com/medals/dynamic/small/16820_medal.gif" border="0" alt="See Carrot Ink Reviews at Bizrate.com" width="112" height="37" /> 
<map name="16820_medal">
<area title="See Carrot Ink Reviews at Bizrate.com" shape="poly" coords="1,0,1,36,61,36,61,20,111,20,111,0" href="//www.bizrate.com/ratings_guide/merchant_detail__mid--16820.html?rf=sur" target="_blank" />
<area title="Bizrate" shape="rect" coords="62,21,111,36" href="//www.bizrate.com/?rf=sur" target="_blank" /> 
</map>
</a></p>
<!-- END: Bizrate Medal (112x37 pixels) --></td>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="2"><br /> <a id="bbblink" class="rbhzbus" style="display: block; position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 100px; height: 38px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" title="Carrot Ink, Ink Cartridge - Refill &amp; Sales, Carrollton, TX" href="http://www.bbb.org/dallas/business-reviews/ink-cartridge-refill-and-sales/carrot-ink-in-carrollton-tx-37007583#bbblogo" target="_blank"><img id="bbblinkimg" style="padding: 0px; border: none;" src="http://seal-dallas.bbb.org/logo/rbhzbus/carrot-ink-37007583.png" alt="Carrot Ink, Ink Cartridge - Refill &amp; Sales, Carrollton, TX" width="200" height="38" /></a>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var bbbprotocol = ( ("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://" ); document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + bbbprotocol + 'seal-dallas.bbb.org' + unescape('%2Flogo%2Fcarrot-ink-37007583.js') + "' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
// ]]></script>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas on how to clean this so magento continues to operate?  Thank you in advance.
++++++++++++
Update: Well - this corrected itself with some code-shaking via the Magento HTML editor.

However, now I don't get a nice separation with the "cell" below it - any ideas on what I haven't Closed which could be messing up the formatting?  Thanks

Comment: install firebug to see the error message

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<table style="width: 312px; background-color: #ffffff; height: 60px; border: 0px solid #949494;" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0" align="center">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;" colspan="2"><br /> <!-- BEGIN: Bizrate Medal (112x37 pixels) -->
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    // <![CDATA[
                    var bizrate={small:"true"};
                    // ]]>
                </script>
                <script src="//medals.bizrate.com/medals/js/16820_medal.js" type="text/javascript">
                <p><a class="br-button"> <img usemap="#16820_medal" src="//medals.bizrate.com/medals/dynamic/small/16820_medal.gif" border="0" alt="See Carrot Ink Reviews at Bizrate.com" width="112" height="37" /> 
                        <map name="16820_medal">
                        <area title="See Carrot Ink Reviews at Bizrate.com" shape="poly" coords="1,0,1,36,61,36,61,20,111,20,111,0" href="//www.bizrate.com/ratings_guide/merchant_detail__mid--16820.html?rf=sur" target="_blank" />
                        <area title="Bizrate" shape="rect" coords="62,21,111,36" href="//www.bizrate.com/?rf=sur" target="_blank" /> 
                        </map>
                        </a></p>
                        <!-- END: Bizrate Medal (112x37 pixels) --></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;" colspan="2"><br /> <a id="bbblink" class="rbhzbus" style="display: block; position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 100px; height: 38px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" title="Carrot Ink, Ink Cartridge - Refill &amp; Sales, Carrollton, TX" href="http://www.bbb.org/dallas/business-reviews/ink-cartridge-refill-and-sales/carrot-ink-in-carrollton-tx-37007583#bbblogo" target="_blank"><img id="bbblinkimg" style="padding: 0px; border: none;" src="http://seal-dallas.bbb.org/logo/rbhzbus/carrot-ink-37007583.png" alt="Carrot Ink, Ink Cartridge - Refill &amp; Sales, Carrollton, TX" width="200" height="38" /></a>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                   // <![CDATA[
                        var bbbprotocol = ( ("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://" ); document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + bbbprotocol + 'seal-dallas.bbb.org' + unescape('%2Flogo%2Fcarrot-ink-37007583.js') + "' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
                   // ]]>
                </script>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Error was in this block of code (script within script tag)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
     var bizrate={small:"true"};
     <script src="//medals.bizrate.com/medals/js/16820_medal.js" type="text/javascript">
     // ]]>
 </script>
```